# chrome extension notification not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, notifications

Trying to build a chrome extension with notifications, and I would like a button that displays a notification. This is the HTML code:

```
    <div><button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button></div>
```

This button shows in the extension, but when I press it, nothing happens. Here is my js code:

```
function notifyMe() {
    var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
}
```

Am I missing any js code? I have no idea

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm following correctly but if you want to show a chrome notification there's actually the [chrome notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications)

I'd do the following:

```
<div><button onclick="notifyMe()">Notify me!</button></div>
```

JS

```
function notifyMe() {
  chrome.notifications.create('some id for this notification', {
    type: 'basic', // "basic", "image", "list", or "progress"
    title: 'a title for this notification',
    message: 'the message you want to show'
  }, function () { // called when the notification is created });
}
```

If you want to use the `Notification` you have to ask for permissions first to use it (taken from the [Web Notifications article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/Using_Web_Notifications)):

```
// At first, let's check if we have permission for notification
// If not, let's ask for it
if (window.Notification && Notification.permission !== "granted") {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (status) {
    if (Notification.permission !== status) {
      Notification.permission = status;
    }
  });
}

function notifyMe() {
  if (window.Notification && Notification.permission === "granted") {
    var n = new Notification("Hi!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is calling the Desktop Notification API and not the Chrome Notification API:

```
var notification = new Notification("Hi there!");
```

Apparently Google modified the level of permission in chrome extension (works perfectly in Chrome 43 +). Just include this line in your manifest.json, and Desktop notifications API will work (as well as the Chrome Notification API):

```
"permissions": [ "notifications", ...etc... ],
```

Adding notifications to the permissions scopes, you can check Notification.permission returns "granted".